# Deriving the dual problem from the complex primal problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I faced the following problem recently. When I was working on an electricity market clearing problem, it is hard for me to derive the dual problem of it, which is necessary to obtain the optimal price.

The original primal problem:
\begin{align}
&\mathop{Maximize}_{p_g^G, p_d^D, \theta_n}{\quad SW = \sum_d U_d p_d^D - \sum_g C_g p_g^G}\\
&subject\quad to:\\
     &0\leq p_d^D \leq \overline{P}_d^D \qquad \forall d \\
     &0\leq p_g^G \leq \overline{P}_g^G \qquad \forall g \\
     &\sum_{d \in \Psi_n} p_d^D + \sum_{m \in \Omega_n}B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m)- \sum_{g \in \Psi_n} p_g^G=0  :\lambda_n \forall n \\
     &-F_{n,m}\leq B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m) \leq F_{n,m} \qquad \forall n, \forall m \\
     &\theta_{ref} = 0
\end{align}

At first, I do it in this way:
I transform the problem into standard format:
\begin{align}
&\mathop{Minimize}_{p_g^G, p_d^D, \theta_n}{\quad SW = -\sum_d U_d p_d^D + \sum_g C_g p_g^G}\\
&subject\quad to:\\
& -p_d^D \leq 0 &:\mu_{d1}^D\\
& -p_g^G \leq 0 &:\mu_{g1}^G\\
& p_d^D-\overline{P}_d^D \leq 0 &:\mu_{d2}^D\\
& p_g^G-\overline{P}_g^G \leq 0 &:\mu_{g2}^{G}\\
&\sum_{d \in \Psi_n} p_d^D + \sum_{m \in \Omega_n}B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m)- \sum_{g \in \Psi_n} p_g^G=0 \quad \forall n &:\lambda_n  \\
&-F_{n,m}- B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m) \leq 0 &:\underline{\eta}_{n,m} \\
& B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m) - F_{n,m} \leq 0 &:\overline{\eta}_{n,m}\\
&\theta_{ref} =0 &:\gamma
\end{align}

And then I derive the lagrangian function:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     L(p,\theta,\mu, \lambda, \eta) 
= &-\sum_d U_d p_d^D + \sum_g C_g p_g^G  - \sum_d{\mu_{d1}^D p_d^D} \\
&- \sum_g {\mu_{g1}^{D} p_g^G} + \sum_d{\mu_{d2}^D(p_d^D - \overline{P}_d^D)} + \sum_g{\mu_{g2}^G(p_g^G-\overline{P}_g^G)} \\
&+ \sum_n{\lambda_n (\sum_{d \in \Psi_n}{p_d^D} + \sum_{m \in \Omega_n}{B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m)}- \sum_{g \in \Psi_n}{p_g^G}}) \\
&- \sum_{n,m} {\underline{\eta}_{n,m}(F_{n,m}+B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m))} \\
&+ \sum_{n,m} {\overline{\eta}_{n,m}(B_{n,m}(\theta_n-\theta_m)-F_{n,m})}+ \gamma \theta_1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

From which I can get the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     &\mathop{Minimize}_{p,\theta} L(p,\theta,\mu, \lambda, \eta) \\
    &= -\sum_d \mu_{d2}^D \overline{P}^D_d - \sum_g \mu_{g2}^G \overline{P}_g^G - \sum_{n,m} \underline{\eta}_{n,m}F_{n,m} - \sum_{n,m} \overline{\eta}_{n,m}F_{n,m}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

However, for your information, The answer is
\begin{align}
    &\mathop{Minimize}_{\mu,\eta,\lambda,\gamma}  \sum_d \mu_{d2}^D \overline{P}^D_d + \sum_g \mu_{g2}^G \overline{P}_g^G + \sum_{n,m} \underline{\eta}_{n,m}F_{n,m} + \sum_{n,m} \overline{\eta}_{n,m}F_{n,m}\\
    &subject \quad to:\\
    & -U_d+\mu_d^D+\lambda_{n \in \Psi_d} \geq 0 :p_d^D \forall d\\
    & C_g+\mu_g^G-\lambda_{n \in \Psi_d} \geq 0 :p_g^G \forall g\\
    &\sum_{m \in \Omega_n} B_{n,m} (\lambda_n-\lambda_m+\overline{\eta}_{n,m}-\overline{\eta}_{m,n}-\underline{\eta}_{n,m}-\underline{\eta}_{m,n})+\gamma=0
    :\theta_n \quad n=ref\\
    &\sum_{m \in \Omega_n} B_{n,m} (\lambda_n-\lambda_m+\overline{\eta}_{n,m}-\overline{\eta}_{m,n}-\underline{\eta}_{n,m}-\underline{\eta}_{m,n})=0
    :\theta_n \quad \forall{n/ref}
\end{align}
Which I don't know how to obtain.
(I know how to do simple primal-dual transformation but this is somehow hard for me to do)

Anyone know how to obtain the dual format of the primal problem shown above? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.